# Validating pre populated input field angular

Tags: angular, validation, client-side-validation

I have the following code:

```
<h1>New Book</h1>
<form  #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(f)">
   <div class="form-group">
        <label for="group">Group</label>
        <select id="group" class="form-control" (change)="onGroupChange()" [(ngModel)]="groupId" name="groupId">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option *ngFor="let g of groups" value="{{g.id}}">{{g.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="registrationNumber">Registration Number</label>
        <input required ngModel name="registrationNumber" #registrationNumber="ngModel" id="registrationNumber" class="form-control" value={{regId}}/>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!registrationNumber && !registrationNumber.valid">Registration Number  is required.</div>
    </div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f.valid">Save</button>
</form>
```

As you can see, the button is disabled if one of the form's values is invalid. The problem is that the registration number is populated when you choose a group in the group drop down list. Even after populating the registration number field, the save button is still disabled.What kind of validation should I write in the *ngIf of the registration Number to tell angular to mark the field as ok if the field has value.

In other words, what should go in the ngIf below?

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf=" ? "**>Registration Number  is required.</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value using `ngModel` and then the validation should work as expected.

```html
<input required [ngModel]="regId" name="registrationNumber" #registrationNumber="ngModel" id="registrationNumber" class="form-control"/>
```

Additionaly, you can simplify your `ngIf` by using the null-coalescing operator

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="!registrationNumber?.valid">Registration Number  is required.</div>
```

Comment: Yes it did. May I kindly know how does adding [ngModel] make the validation work ? I mean, what's the connection here?

Comment: Angular forms use the model value to determine validity. When you bind to the html value property `ngModel` is unaware that the input has a value. Also, the `[ngModel]` syntax is just an input value so you are telling it to use that value initially but it will be overwritten and not kept in sync when the user changes it.

Comment: I kind of got you a little. Can you point me to a tutorial which might explain this in detail?

Comment: Relevant documentation: [Track control state and validity with ngModel](https://angular.io/guide/forms#track-control-state-and-validity-with-ngmodel)